# expression for the sum involving digamma function

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, closed-form

I got this answer from WolframAlpha. Does anyone know how even to approach it to obtain the solution using digamma function. Please don't solve it, just show me in the right direction!

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}{1 \over n^{2} - 4\left(k - 1\right)^{2}}
={\pi n\cot\left(\pi n/2\right) - n\Psi\left(n/2\right) + n\Psi\left(3 n/2\right)
+ 2 \over 4 n^{2}}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [series for digamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula). Look for a similar series for cot. (I hope I didn't reveal too much :)

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over n^{2} - 4\pars{k - 1}^{2}}
={\pi n\cot\pars{\pi n/2} - n\Psi\pars{n/2} + n\Psi\pars{3 n/2} + 2
  \over 4 n^{2}}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#c00000}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over n^{2} - 4\pars{k - 1}^{2}}}
> =-\,{1 \over 4}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over k^{2} - n^{2}/4}
> =-\,{1 \over 4}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over \pars{k + n/2}\pars{k - n/2}}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{1 \over 4}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{%
> {1 \over \pars{k + n/2}\pars{k - n/2}} - {1 \over \pars{k + 3n/2}\pars{k + n/2}}}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{1 \over 4}\,
> {\Psi\pars{n/2} - \Psi\pars{-n/2} \over \pars{n/2} - \pars{-n/2}}
> + {1 \over 4}\,
> {\Psi\pars{3n/2} - \Psi\pars{n/2} \over \pars{3n/2} - \pars{n/2}}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\Psi\pars{z}}$ is the
>   [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm). See ${\bf\mbox{6.3.1}}$ in that link.

$$
\color{#c00000}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over n^{2} - 4\pars{k - 1}^{2}}}
={\Psi\pars{3n/2} - 2\Psi\pars{n/2} + \Psi\pars{-n/2} \over 4n}\tag{1}
$$

> With [formula](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.3.7}}$ we'll get
>   $$
> \Psi\pars{-\,{n \over 2}} = \Psi\pars{1 + {n \over 2}}
> -\pi\cot\pars{\pi\bracks{-\,{n \over 2}}}
> $$

Moreover, $\ds{\Psi\pars{1 + n/2} = \Psi\pars{n/2} + 1/\pars{n/2}}$ where we used
the [identity](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.3.5}}$
such that:
$$
\Psi\pars{-\,{n \over 2}}
=\Psi\pars{n \over 2} + {2 \over n} + \pi\cot\pars{\pi n \over 2}
$$

> The final answer is found by replacing this result in expression $\pars{1}$.